# Regular Expression related: first character alphabet second onwards alphanumeric+some special characters

Tags: regex

I have one question related with regular expression. In my case, I have to make sure that
first letter is alphabet, second onwards it can be any alphanumeric + some special characters.

Regards,
Anto

Comment: Please edit your question to provide samples of your input. Make clear the ones you want to accept and those you want to reject.

Answer (score 30):

Try something like this:

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9.,$;]+$
```

Explanation:

```
^                Start of line/string.
[a-zA-Z]         Character is in a-z or A-Z.
[a-zA-Z0-9.,$;]  Alphanumeric or `.` or `,` or `$` or `;`.
+                One or more of the previous token (change to * for zero or more).
$                End of line/string.
```

The special characters I have chosen are just an example. Add your own special characters as appropriate for your needs. Note that a few characters need escaping inside a character class otherwise they have a special meaning in the regular expression.

I am assuming that by "alphabet" you mean A-Z. Note that in some other countries there are also other characters that are considered letters.

**More information**

- [Character Classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)
- [Repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)
- [Anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)

Comment: i did this sort of thing but what happens is that it takes part in the sense if i have entered a999#& and if & is not permitted then it takes a999# and go ahead with it. What i want to is to stick with it such that if anything is not proper then it simply discards.

Comment: @anto: Did you remember the `$` anchor at the end of the regular expression?

Comment: Even after adding $ it did not work. I mean, it takes part up to invalid character as i said above.

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```
 /^[a-zA-Z]/
```

where

```
 ^ -> Starts with 
 [a-zA-Z] -> characters to match
```

Comment: And what about the other characters?

Comment: If you don't have a need for matching any other characters, then this would still work. However if you need to match any other character after 1st character to be alphabet, you can use the same sequence.For example : ^[a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{2} -> This would validate the 1st character to be an alphabet and then the next 2 as numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest answer is to pick and match only the first character with regex.

```
String str = "s12353467457458";
if ((""+str.charAt(0)).matches("^[a-zA-Z]")){
    System.out.println("Valid");
}
```