# Regular Expression for name

Tags: java, android, regex

I want an regular expression in JAVA that matches the below conditions :

1. Should starts with alphabet ie **a-z** or **A-Z**
2. Should contain only alphabets and digits

```
String pattern = "/^[A-Za-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*/i";

Pattern ps = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher ms = ps.matcher(src.toString());

if (ms.matches())
{
        return src;
}
else
{
        String s = "";
        try {
                s = src.toString();
                if(s.length()>0)
                s = s.substring(0, s.length()-1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
                s = "";
        }
        return s;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this "^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*" But not working

Comment: @KK_07k11A0585 In that case please add an example source string, and the code you are using to match it (not just the regex).

Comment: @GergoErdosi This is my code http://pastebin.com/YR1eYZF7

Comment: I have also tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690855/regular-expression-related-first-character-alphabet-second-onwards-alphanumeric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to know is the generic regular expression which starts with any alphabets and has only alpha-numeric characters in it.
Look, the generic format (in java, for string pattern matching) for your query is this:

```
String pattern = "[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*";
```

or

```
String pattern = "[a-zA-Z](\\w)*";
```

- represents kleene star operator which denotes the occurrences with one or more.
  \w consists of the word characters.

Then further you can use pattern-matcher functions to do your work.

Comment: It's okay. The problem is not with your caret sign using. As mentioned earlier, you are trying to use both: forward slash and double quotes together, which was creating the issue.